# не понимаю ошибку в switch

Tags: c++, switch, case

Здраствуйте! Перехожу с C# на C++ и столкнулся с проблемой:

```
#include <iostream>

char chooseSimbol() {
    char s;
    std::cout << "\n\n\tВыберите символ, которым будет рисоваться линия: ";
    std::cin >> s;
    system("cls");
    return s;
    }

int chooseLineLength() {
    int lineLength;
    std::cout << "\n\n\tВведите длину линию: ";
    std::cin >> lineLength;
    system("cls");
    return lineLength;
}

int main()
{ 
    setlocale(LC_ALL, "ru");
    std::cout << "\n\n\n\t\t\t\t\tРисовальщик линии \n\n\n";
    std::cout << "\n\tКакую линию вы будете рисовать?"
        << "\n\t[1] - Горизонтальную"
        << "\n\t[2] - Вертикальную"
        << "\n\n\t\t> ";

    int menuA;
    std::cin >> menuA;
    system("cls");

    switch (menuA)
    {
        case 1:
            char s = chooseSimbol();
            int a = chooseLineLength();
            for (int i = 0; i < a; i++) {
                std::cout << s;
            }
        break;

        case 2:
            char s = chooseSimbol();
            int a = chooseLineLength();
            for (int i = 0; i < a; i++) {
                std::cout << s << "\n";
            }
        break;

    }
}
```

Данный код выдаёт ошибки:

- a: переопределение; множественная инициализация
- s: переопределение; множественная инициализация
- пропуск инициализации "a" из-за метки "case"
- пропуск инициализации "s" из-за метки "case"

Однако, если заменить Switch() на обычные операторы ветвления, то всё работает именно так, как мне нужно в данном примере:

```
if (menuA == 1) {
    char s = chooseSimbol();
    int a = chooseLineLength();
    for (int i = 0; i < a; i++) {
        std::cout << s;
    }
}
else {
    char s = chooseSimbol();
    int a = chooseLineLength();
    for (int i = 0; i < a; i++) {
        std::cout << s << "\n";
    }
}
```

Первые две ошибки я вроде бы исправил, сделав индивидуальный идентификатор каждой переменной, но не понимаю почему дебаг ругается на это, разве case 1 и case 2 - это не две разные области видимости?

Вторые две ошибки я никак не могу решить.

Comment: Я исправил вторые две ошибки, но всё равно не понимаю. Короче я тупо добавил области видимости для каждого case:
case 1 {
...
}
case 2 {
...
}

У Switch просто такой синтаксис? Я вроде бы когда листал статью про Switch не видел этого

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Само по себе `case` не определяет область видимости, так что ваши объявления переменных оказались в одном блоке. Грубо, как если бы вы напиcали

```
int x = 1;
int x = 2;
```

Просто поместите код каждого `case` в фигурные скобки:

```
case 1:
    {
        char s = chooseSimbol();
        int a = chooseLineLength();
        for (int i = 0; i < a; i++) {
            std::cout << s;
        }
    }
    break;

case 2:
    {
        char s = chooseSimbol();
        int a = chooseLineLength();
        for (int i = 0; i < a; i++) {
            std::cout << s << "\n";
        }
    }
    break;
```

Тем самым вы ограничиваете области видимости до нужного уровня :)

Comment: А почему break не в скобках?)

Comment: думаю, делал на скорую руку)

Comment: @АлексейКарпунов, вряд ли. Работать-то будет одинаково.

Comment: @Qwertiy А надо? Я лично привык к такому виду записи `switch`. Оно как бы подводит итог под веткой :)

Comment: @Harry, ну вот и интересно, почему. Я внутрь помещаю. Как бы всё тело case'а делаю блоком. А в твоём варианте получается блок плюс break. Подумал, может тоже какая-то ассоциация есть, зачем оно так.

Comment: @Qwertiy Фигурные скобки формируют внутреннюю область видимости, по-этому все объявления локальных переменных и код, который к ним обращается, должны быть заключены в них. Оператор `break` относится к конструкции `switch/case`, по-этому без разницы, находится ли он в фигурных скобках, или вне этих скобок.

Comment: @LShadow77, я в курсе. Вопрос был именно про стиль.

Comment: @Harry, а вижу, ты тоже коммент дополнил)

Comment: @Qwertiy вопросы про стиль обычно не имеют чётких ответов. Либо так принято в конкретной команде разработчиков, либо просто потому, что так нравится. Эта тема из той же оперы, что и "на какой строке ставить `{`".

Comment: Ох, знаю я одного человека, который с пеной у рта топит за то, что break должен быть исключительно за скобками, ещё и со странным форматированием. У меня есть смутные подозрения.

Comment: @KoVadim ...что это я? :)

Comment: то, что читали одну и ту же книгу. Мне так и не смог человек объяснить, почему такой синтаксис ему кажется единственно правильным.

Comment: @KoVadim Единственно правильный стиль — это что-то вроде оксюморона...

Comment: если во всем большом проекте что то пишется по одному, а один человек решил по другому, то наверно ему не нужно так делать

Comment: @KoVadim А какое этот пример имеет отношение к тезису о "единственно правильном стиле"? Кстати, не раз тут мой ответ был "если пишете сами для себя — делайте так, как вам удобно и как через полгода вам не придется мучительно вспоминать, что же это тут написано. Если в коллективе — то так, как принято в этом коллективе". Для ответов на ruSO какой-то конкретный стиль не принят :)

Comment: я знаю, что тут нет "единого стиля", но вот этот конкретный стиль сильно-сильно выделяется.  И мне интересно его происхождение  (этого стиля0

Comment: Если о моем `break` — то просто не помню. Как теперь кажется, всегда так писал :) Просто удобнее, визуально четко виден `break` непосредственно перед следующим `case`, очевидно отсутствие проваливания, снижает шансы случайно "провалиться" в следующий `case`... Наверное, так. @KoVadim

Comment: вот вот. и тут та же история - второй человек, который не может объяснить этот странный код.

Comment: @KoVadim Ну, объясните его противоположность :) Дискуссия зашла куда-то в никуда...

Comment: противоположность - легко - практически вся кодовая база так выглядит.

Comment: Добавлю к дискуссии свои 5 копеек -- break после скобочного блока в case выглядит более осмысленно, чем break в нем.